# Question about normality of an infinite sequence

Tags: normal-distribution

Imagine the infinite sequence 0.1223334444… where the integers repeat n times (at some point 88 88’s is followed by 99 99’s). Is this number normal? My intuition suggests the higher integers appear more frequently but I’m not sure.

Comment: How does the decimal expansion react once you get past nine 9's? Do you have ten 10's? And then eleven 11's? In other words, does it go like this:
$$
0.122333444455555666666777777788888888999999999101010101010101010101111\ldots?
$$
Because in that case, there would at some point be eighty-eight 88's followed by eighty-nine 89's. Which is not what you said.

Comment: @Arthur assuming that's what OP meant, the question is actually quite interesting. I wonder if $1$ is more common than the other single-digit integers, because of Benford's law?

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to figure out how many ones (say) there are among the first $N$ digits. I suspect the proportion of ones (or of any other specific digit) does not converge to a limit as $N\to\infty$, but rather oscillates between to values that don't get closer together.

Comment: Arthur, I think what you said is equivalent to what I said. What confuses me is if you stop at, say, twenty two 22’s, there is a preponderance of 2’s. And at 666 666’s, then, 6. How can we answer if we can always select any one of the ten digits to dominate simply by choosing the right expansion? Yet don’t 9’s dominate every sequence preceding the next power of ten string? Forgive my attempts at the right language here.

Comment: You said 88 88s followed by 99 99s, Roz. Arthur said 88 88s followed by 89 89s. Those are not at all equivalent.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A098129 and https://oeis.org/A361751

Comment: I tried to calculate the proportion of ones out to various values of $N$. Out to 9 9s, there's 1 one, and 45 digits, so proportion $.0222$. Out to 19 19s, I count 157 ones out of 335 digits, $.4687$. Out to 99 99s, 605 one out of 9855 digits, $.0614$. Out to 199 199s, 16811 ones out of 54705 digits, $.3073$. Maybe it's converging, but slowly. (And someone should check my counts.)

Comment: Apologies. Arthur correctly suggested the sequence I originally meant. Hazards of 1 A.M. musing. Gerry, subsequently I did think to find your first OEIS sequence. I love OEIS, contributed a couple myself back in the modest 180K’s. But don’t find the database answers my original question. Leaning more towards non-normality (interestingly not abnormality, reserved for a wholly different definition). Here’s why: consider every segment of the sequence where repeating numbers have the same magnitude if 10, e.g., 111 111’s - 999 999’s. You certainly end up with more 9’s. Does this trivialize it all?